# Why Does Getting/Setting Auto_Ptr Cause This Compiler Error

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have a map of auto_ptr's and I am simply trying to set and get map elements but its producing compiler errors. I don't understand what the compiler error means and whats going wrong?

Get compiler error:

> [Error] passing 'const std::auto_ptr' as 'this' argument of
>   'std::auto_ptr<_Tp>::operator std::auto_ptr_ref<_Tp1>() [with _Tp1 =
>   int; _Tp = int]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Set compiler error:

> [Error] no match for 'operator=' (operand types are
>   'std::map, std::auto_ptr >::mapped_type
>   {aka std::auto_ptr}' and 'int*')

Also I've heard it's not advised to use auto_ptr's in standard c++ library collections (list, vector, map). What kind of smart pointer should I use in the below code?

```
std::map <std::string, std::auto_ptr<int> > myMap;

// Throws compiler error
std::auto_ptr <int> a = myMap["a"];
// Also throws compiler error
myMap["a"] = new int;
```

Comment: Use `unique_ptr`. `auto_ptr` will be removed from C++ soon.

Comment: @chris `unique_ptr` doesn't work here either (it has deleted copy-assignment)

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Good point, you can't do the first one (the second should be fine). At that point, it's a question of whether you want to share ownership with the map or take ownership from it.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `unique_ptr` *may* be a reasonable choice, but `std::auto_ptr <int> a = myMap["a"];` should then be updated to e.g. `const std::auto_ptr<int>& a = myMap["a"];`, and similarly changes to the pointer should be made using the [`unique_ptr` API](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr): `myMap["a"].reset(new int);`.  `shared_ptr`'s another alternative....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `auto_ptr`. It has broken semantics and is deprecated. The proper pointer for single-ownership semantics is *unique_ptr*.

You can have:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<int> > myMap;
```

Now, when you write `myMap["a"]`, an entry in the map will be created for `"a"`, and this returns a reference to that. The entry created is `std::unique_ptr<int>{}` which is a "null" pointer.

You can make this point somewhere, however you use the member function `reset` for that, not the assignment operator:

```
myMap["a"].reset( new int{5} );
```

or alternatively, since C++14,

```
myMap["a"] = std::make_unique<int>(5);
```

Your other doesn't quite make sense, if you want single ownership. You can either look at the raw pointer value, or you can take ownership. To take ownership:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> new_owner = std::move(myMap["a"]);
```

which will leave the existing map entry as a "null" pointer again, and `new_owner` has ownership.

If you just want to do something with the raw pointer in the map then you can use `get()` to get that pointer, or use the dereference operator directly on the `unique_ptr`:

```
myMap["a"].reset( new int{5} );
int *raw = myMap["a"].get();
*myMap["a"] = 6;
```

Comment: Note that the first paragraph isn't an opinion. The semantics of `std::auto_ptr`  are not compatible with the semantics of  `std::map`.